# Верстка html письма

Tags: html, css, email

Привет.

Столкнулся с проблемой. Сверстал письмо для рассылки, ставлю фон через **background="long.jpg"**.
Отображается только в gmail, но не срабатывает background-size, и в mail отображается все идеально, в рамблере и яндексе не хочет работать. Каким способом можно реализовать?

Делаю все в таблицах.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433378/178988

Answer (score 2):

> 4. [Наложения фона](http://habrahabr.ru/post/252279/)
>
> Свойства `background=""` `bgcolor=""` можно применять только для тега
>   `<table>`
>
> так как gmail не воспринимает эти свойства в других тегах, если
>   заходить на почту с помощью браузера Safari.
>
> Не стоит использовать CSS свойства для наложения фона, они будут
>   игнорироваться некоторыми почтовыми клиентами:
>
> `background:  background-image: background-position: background-size:`

используйте `bgcolor` для фонового цвета.


 По поводу "как реализовать фоновое изображение?" - старайтесь использовать не фоновые, а обычные изображения + тестирование: пробуйте и надейтесь :)

Answer (score 2):

Могу сказать с уверенностью, что "***почта yandex***" и "***yahoo mail***" отображают фоновую картинку с атрибута **background**. Убедитесь, что указали верный путь к фоновой картинке и что [тег поддерживает](http://xiper.net/manuals/html/attributes/background) данный атрибут.

**P.S:** бывают случаи, когда почтовые клиенты не подгружают фоновую картинку вместе с другими изображениями, пока пользователь не даст разрешение на их загрузку

Answer (score 1):

Загрузка картинок почтовыми клиентами часто не производится до явного разрешения пользователя или добавления адреса отправителя в специальный белый список. Это связано с тем, что в случае уникального адреса картинки сервер по пришедшему запросу узнает, что письмо было открыто.