# Пропадают классы css в письмах

Tags: php, css, вёрстка, email

Есть верстка письма для рассылки. Все css-стили написаны в теле документа для рассылки. Все стили привязаны к html-тегам с помощью классов.

Отправляем письмо с помощью mail(), PHP. Видим на почте (mail.ru, gmail.com, yandex.ru) письмо без стилей. Причем нету даже css классов, есть только теги.

А если открыть тоже письмо в Thunderbird к примеру - то все классы есть и письмо выглядит красиво.

Пробовал перемещать стили, ужимать стили, менять кавычки классов с двойных на одинарные, читать текст рассылки из файла и вставлять его прямо в php-код.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. Спасибо.

Comment: Потому что для писем не действует стандарт HTML, это обман, чтобы набрать классы. Наиболее совместимый способ - писать inline-стилями.

Comment: Хм. Ок, попробую.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

При верстке писем рекомендуется писать все стили инлайновыми.

То есть не создавать селекторы, классы и так далее, а писать стили в теге style

Например:

```
<div style="background:red;">
```

Answer (score 5):

## Habrahabr

- [Верстка email рассылок от А до Я для чайников](http://habrahabr.ru/post/252279/)
- [Верстка почтовых рассылок: взгляд изнутри](http://habrahabr.ru/post/114119/)
- [10 рекомендаций по html-верстке электронных писем](http://habrahabr.ru/post/60420/)
- [Верстка почтовых рассылок](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112163/)
- [5 правил верстки email-писем от Печкина](http://habrahabr.ru/company/pechkin/blog/182964/)
- [How-to: Правила вёрстки email-писем](http://habrahabr.ru/company/pechkin/blog/255819/)

Answer (score 0):

В письмах можно использовать только инлайнстили. Всё остальное (стили, скрипты, классы) вырезают web-почтовики. Простая безопасность.

Думаю что и в Thunderbird в настройках можно поставить такое поведение. Так что только инлайнстили. Если используются картинки в письме - то только через прямые ссылки и тег img, никаких background-image